# Any ideas on how to make a python bot that automatically types on a webpage?

Tags: python, bots

I'm trying to make a bot to see how far I can get in hackertyper and I don't want to sit at my pc and type, I wanna make a bot for it. Amy ideas on how I can do that?

Comment: You can use https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://hackertyper.net/')

for i in range(100):
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.send_keys("I'm trying to make a bot to see how far I can get in hackertyper...")
    actions.perform()
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

Comment: I'll try it....

Comment: I've ran into a problem where it will just stop, it wont keep going.

Comment: If you just copied and pasted the code I wrote then it will stop after 100 iterations. You should have been able to figure out how to turn the `for` loop into an infinite loop if that was what you wanted.

Comment: If you cannot do that yourself, then I suggest you go through one or two python tutorials.

Comment: I figured it out in the book I was reading, thanks anyways.